# A lot of calls for to the WebService on the same time in asp.net

Tags: web-services

I have a .net web method like this:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld1(string emri)
    {
        return emri;
    }
```

If for example 80 users call this web service in the same time from another platform(andorid application or whatever) what will happen? Is there a possibility for a deadlock or maybe for each user there will be an object using this web service?

What happens in general if there are many calls on the same time for such a web service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whole books are written on this subject.

There is no risk of deadlock for your piece of sample code as it simply returns the value that the caller passed in.

Briefly, for a real web service where callers presumably would access some shared resource(s), like databases and such, you would protect those resources with appropriate locking so that two users don't get an opportunity to change the same data at once.

Comment: actually yes in this web service I will user the sql database. I will update an object in database. In this case how can I protect my database? I am using EntityFramework.